Cloudflare Tunnel: "Unable to reach the origin service" When Accessing Local HTTP API / Bad Gateway
I'm running a local API on port 8504 and trying to expose it via Cloudflare Tunnel. When I access the API directly with curl from my local machine, it works fine:
curl "http://localhost:8504/query-stream?text=minimal%20hello%20world%20in%20python&rag=false"

or using its internal Docker IP:
curl "http://172.20.121.5:8504/query-stream?text=minimal%20hello%20world%20in%20python&rag=false"

It returns:
data: {"init": true, "model": "llama3"}
data: {"token": "A"}
data: {"token": " simple"}
data: {"token": " yet"} ...

However, when trying to reach it through the Cloudflare tunnel with the public domain:
curl "http://api.example.com/query-stream?text=minimal%20hello%20world%20in%20python&rag=false"

I get a repeated redirect error:
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare</center>
</body>
</html>

Additionally, I receive an error from genai-stack-cloudflared (in Docker logs):
ERR  error="Unable to reach the origin service. The service may be down or it may not be responding to traffic from cloudflared: dial tcp 172.20.121.5:8504: i/o timeout"

Setup Details:

Local API: Genai-stack hosted on Docker, reachable at http://localhost:8504 or http://172.20.121.5:8504

Cloudflare Tunnel: Configured as a service together with the Docker Compose file:
cloudflared:
    image: cloudflare/cloudflared:latest
    command: tunnel --no-autoupdate run --token ${TUNNEL_TOKEN} 
    environment:
      - TUNNEL_TOKEN=${TUNNEL_TOKEN}
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - tunnel

api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: api.Dockerfile
    ...
    networks:
      - net
      - tunnel
    ...
    ports:
      - 8504:8504


Domain: Exposed as https://api.example.com through Cloudflare tunnel. The tunnel is healthy and connects to the local service at http://172.20.121.5:8504.


Troubleshooting Done So Far:

Verified the local API is accessible from localhost and internal Docker IP.
Attempted curl requests from both internal IP and localhost, confirming the API responds as expected.
Enabled all Access-Control-Allow-Origin policies in the application.
Disabled Automatic HTTPS Rewrites and Always Use HTTPS in Cloudflare settings.
Create service token for curl -L -H "CF-Access-Client-Id: <CLIENT_ID>" -H "CF-Access-Client-Secret: <CLIENT_SECRET>" "http://api.example.com/query-stream?text=minimal%20hello%20seikai%20in%20python&rag=false"

Despite these steps, the Cloudflare tunnel logs keep showing "Unable to reach the origin service" with an I/O timeout.
Question:
How can I resolve this timeout issue between Cloudflare Tunnel and my local HTTP API? Could it be related to HTTPS redirection or network configuration in Docker/Cloudflare? Any insights would be appreciated!

Finally, I solved this crap through step by step reasoning (flipping the whole table).

Ensure all services (including Cloudflare tunnel) connected to the same network in the docker-compose.yml file:

    network:
        - net


Allow everything on all Access-Control-x-x at the application setting
Turning off Always-Use-Https or Rewrite-HTTP-to-HTTPS
Create a service token

My command look like this: curl -L -H "CF-Access-Client-Id: <CLIENT_ID>" -H "CF-Access-Client-Secret: <CLIENT_SECRET>" https://api.example.com/query-stream/...
Till here, the docker still giving "Unable to reach the origin service" error. I almost give up, but then, I give it another try. Luckily, I saw this article https://community.cloudflare.com/t/curl-access-with-service-token/198228. So, I learnt that one should choose Service Auth instead of Allow for the policy action when using a service token.

Very gooooood :D
ps: I hope that it can still work fine after restarting my docker container.

It is working great so far.  The curl command with service token works on any device connected to the Internet. I also found that HTTPS or HTTP is not relate to the error that arises.
